# hyperlinking in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, hyperref

I am using a Ubuntu 12.04 machine in which I have loaded LaTeX (packages from CTAN, not the default ones). I want to bring hyperlinks in the bibliography files. Though my bib file contains all the informations (including the doi and hyperlinks) after compiling they do not appear in the pdf. I believe it is due to some some of my commands in the header files, because when I write a Physical Rev articles using REVTeX, they do appear in the place. For reference, I am giving the necessary parts

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amsfonts,amssymb, color, cite, bbm}
\usepackage{latexsym, graphicx, pstricks,rotating,subfig}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=darkblue,
unicode=true,pdfauthor=rsg,bookmarks=false}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem{eg}{Example}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\newtheorem{note}{Note}
```

and as usual it ends with

```
\bibliographystyle{h-physrev}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

I could not find out what mistake I am making. For reference, I have picked up the style file [h-physrev](https://static.arxiv.org/static/arxiv.marxdown/0.1/help/hypertex/bibstyles/h-physrev.bst).
I am not sure where this is a duplicate question. Solutions given in the related questions does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is due to the `\bibliographystyle` you are picking.

For example, if I use `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranSN}` (along with the `hyperref` and `url` packages) I get the following output:

[image]

Each bibliography style decides what to show, and you could customize this at your will.  Please see this question for more information:

[Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles)

**Please note that the reason there are backreferences is because I set it so.  The normal `IEEEtranSN` does not include them.